# Convert an int array to an unsigned char array for AES encryption

Tags: c, aes, bit, unsigned-char

I got an array

```
int key[128] = {1,0,1,0,0,1, .........., 0,1,0}
```

I want to convert this array to

```
unsigned char key1[16] = {0x__,0x__,...,0x__}
```

for example if

```
from key[0] to key[7] is 10100011, then key1[0] = 0xa3
```

I need use this new array for AES encryption

Comment: If you need a fiexed bitwidth use fixed width types from `stdint.h`. Test also provide a defined representating of signed integers.

Comment: As I understand, you're asking how to *convert an array of integer 1's and 0's to a byte array*, and this has nothing to do with encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the *lsb* is `key[0]`, and the *msb* is `key[7]`

```
int key[128] = {1,0,1,0,0,1, .........., 0,1,0}
unsigned char key1[16];

int (* better_key)[8] = (int (*)[8])key;

int i;
int j;

for (i=0;i<sizeof(key1); i++){
     key1[i]=0;
     for(j=0;j<8;j++){
       key1[i]|=better_key[i][j]<<j;
     }
}
```

If the *msb* is `key[0]`, and the *lsb* is `key[7]`, just replace

`better_key[i][j]`

with

`better_key[i][7-j]`

Answer (score 0):

Go though each element of `key[]` adding (or'ing) in its bit-position value to the corresponding element of `key1[]`.

```
#define N 128
#define B8 8

int key[N] = {1,0,1,0,0,1, .........., 0,1,0}
unsigned char key1[N/B8] = { 0 };

for (unsigned i = 0; i<N; i++) {
  key1[i/B8] |= key[i] << (B8 - 1 - (i%B8));
}
```